# Поиск нецензурных слов в словах

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, как cделать простую и не очень медленную проверку отправляемого текста на сервер на наличие матов?
Т.е ввел юзер плохие слова и идет проверка с коллекцией плохих слов.

Comment: Вы же знаете о низкой эффективности и ложных срабатываниях таких проверок, да?

Comment: Посмотрите, например, как это реализовано в скрипте Censure, ссылки: https://github.com/rin-nas/php-censure и http://forum.dklab.ru/viewtopic.php?p=166584

Comment: и как вариант:
http://bally-36.livejournal.com/66906.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну так над этой проблемой люди уже не первый год сражаются ) Я имею ввиду самая большая проблема - это оригинальность людей. Даже если в БД плохих слов добавить всякие искажение в духе "млять", люди всё равно начнут использовать там звёздочки какие нибудь, символы. А в конце концов просто оригинальный унижения придумают (хотя если проблема именно мат - то ничего страшного). Но если нужно просто проверить слово на совпадение с какими то образцами, то:

1) используем `split("\s+");` чтобы разбить всё по словам. И дальше можно тупым свитчем перебирать. Более красиво - циклом по массиву матов. Ещё более красиво - бинарный поиск по хэшам. Не знаю какие там методы использует `HashMap`, поэтому советовать не буду, но когда хотят скорости - используют именно его.

2) Огромный длинный regex, который будет искать маты. Вот это вариант поинтересней, Regex конечно нужно формировать из отдельных подстрок, чтобы код не забить. то будет красиво выглядеть, но вот не уверен насчет производительности. Пусть в комментариях напишут, если моё мнение, что это медленно - неверно.

И по ходу не забывайте про всякие хитрости, в духе `toLowerCase`, дабы не городить ещё варианты с большими буквами. Сам список слов тоже можно автоматизировать, например предлоги + мат. Потом там гласные позаменять. Опять же кодом, а не руками. И в качестве инициализации, а не при каждой проверке. Сама проверка должна быть просто перебором возможных вариантов. И всё будет летать )

И ещё забыл. Способ, которым вы будете делать зависит от цели. Если у вас серьёзное приложение, то элементарно десяток-другой матов остановят 99% людей. Скорее как правило сработает, для людей которые по эмоциям написали "а, нельзя мат, ну ладно". Если же какой то средненький форум, я бы тоже не заморачивался. Но а если крупный детский ресурс, например и для вас это важная задача + очень много школьников - там придется извратится. А так вообще я бы пошел путем назначения модерации, вместо всяких этих заморочек.

Comment: скажите,а нужно ли для первого варианта решения создавать отдельный поток?

Comment: Нет, не нужно. Я сомневаюсь, что нормальным образом написанная функция будет работать дольше скажем 100мс. А пользователь это не заметить, вы скорее всего больше времени потеряете на запуске потока (дадада, запуск потока тоже занимает время) )